# Area of a submanifold defined by an equation

Tags: integration, geometry, differential-geometry

My purpose is to find the surface area of a torus defined by the equation : $$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-a)^2+z^2=r^2$$
where $a,r$ are parameters such that the torus is non degenerated.

First I know a mean of calculating its surface : with the parametrization :$$\phi : (u,v) \mapsto ((a+r \cos u) \cos v ,(a+r \cos u) \sin v,r \sin u)$$ :

Then : $$Area= \int _{torus} dp = \int _{u,v \in ]0,2 \pi[} \|\phi _u (u,v) \times \phi _v (u,v)\| dudv = 4 \pi ^2 ar$$

My question is :

> How can I calculate this area without the parametrisation of the surface, just with the equation (and without using the rotating symetry) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Pappus' Centroid Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem)

Comment: It works only for revolution solids, I am looking for something only using an equation $F(x)=0$

Comment: @JohnMarjan You should mention clearly in your question.  Also the **surface area** is more proper wording than **area**.